# How do I see the "Do you want to run this application" from this publisher dialog again for a JNLP

Tags: firefox, jnlp

I clicked on the checkbox shown [image: here].

Now I dialog is not shown again. However for testing purpose I need to reset this setting so that I can see the dialog again. How do I do that? I couldn't find where this setting is stored.

I am on Firefox 57.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset Java's security warnings. To do so you need to enter this in a command prompt (use cmd.exe or Terminal to get a prompt):

```
javaws -viewer
```

Then 2 dialog boxes pop up. You can dismiss the frontmost 'Java Cache Viewer' (see note on that below). The 'Java Control Panel' has 5 tabs at the top, where you click **Security**, and then **Restore Security Prompts**

[ General ][ Update ][ Java ][ **Security** ][ Advanced ]

[image]

Note: *The Java Cache Viewer could be useful in testing. It allows you to remove a previously used JNLP app.*